# How to use .Net System.IO; System.Net; System.Net.Sockets; from Visual Studio C++ project?

Tags: .net, c++

How to use .Net `System.IO;  System.Net; System.Net.Sockets;` libs from Visual Studio C++ project?

Comment: Are you having trouble using them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are managed assemblies, meaning you will have to use C++/CLI. Wikipedia has some pretty good information on that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

[edit] Also, of course, there's the MSDN article on C++/CLI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379617(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to create C++/CLI project for this. For existing native C++ project, add CLI support to it: Project - Properties - Configuration Properties - Common Language Runtime Support - /clr.